# Отмена таймера из другой функции другого модуля (aiogram)

Tags: python, таймер, aiogram

Всем доброго времени суток! Пишу бота для телеги с помощью библиотеки aiogram, и возникла небольшая проблема.

Суть: в модуле payments.py есть хэндлер, при срабатывании которого инициализируется таймер из модуля timer.py. Нужно, чтобы при срабатывании другого хэндлера (уже из другого модуля confirm.py) созданный в payments.py таймер отменялся. Код:

```
# Модуль timer.py
import asyncio

class Timer:
def __init__(self, time, query, state, callback):
    self._timeout = time
    self._query = query
    self._state = state
    self._callback = callback
    self._task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._job())

async def _job(self):
    await asyncio.sleep(self._timeout)
    await self._callback(self._query, self._state)

def cancel(self):

    self._task.cancel()
```

Модуль `payments.py`

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(state=MakeTask.chooseTime)
async def choosePayment_cb(query: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict, state: FSMContext):
    timer = Timer(60, query, state, timeout)
   
async def timeout(query, state):
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat.id, message_id=query.message.message_id,
                            text=f'Время истекло')
```

Модуль `confirm.py`

```
 @dp.callback_query_handler(state=MakeTask.confirm)
    async def confirm_cb(query: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict, state: FSMContext):
        # Тут нужно отменить таймер командой timer.cancel(), но как передать экземпляр timer в текущий хэндлер?
```

Пересмотрел очень много материала на разных сайтах и нигде не смог найти подходящее решение. Вообще нет идей ввиду недостатка опыта. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать? Спасибо!

UPD1:
Мне понравилось предложение [@eri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16574/eri), почитал информацию, небольшое продвижение есть. Но опять застрял :С Как мне добавить проверку на этот эвент? Попробовал такой вариант, но он мне не подходит, нужно, чтобы как только эвент происходил, так сразу же отменялся таймер. Код:

```
async def _run_timer(self, time, cancel_event):
print("Таймер запущен!")
seconds = 0
while seconds < time:
    if not cancel_event.is_set():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        seconds += 1
    else:
        self.cancel(cancel_event)
print('Таймер успешно завершён!')
await self._callback()

def cancel(self, cancel_event):
    cancel_event.clear()
    print('Отмена таймера!')
    self._task.cancel()
```

Comment: Как самый простой вариант - объявить его в глобальной переменной `timer` и импортировать в confirm.py: `from payment import timer`

Comment: а ещё можно эвентом) если хочется грейсфульно его остановить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражаю огромную благодарность [@eri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16574/eri) за предложенную идею. В течение нескольких дней пытался реализовать "идеальный" для себя таймер, который как только получает event, так сразу отменяет таймер и сразу же выполняет callback, предназначенный для отмены. Но, увы и ах, не вышло. Пришлось немного покостылить. Надеюсь, кому-нибудь поможет даже такой экзотичный способ отмены таймера.

Модуль `timer.py`:

```
import asyncio

cancel_event = asyncio.Event()

class Timer:
def __init__(self, time, query, state, event, callback):
    self._timeout = time
    self._query = query
    self._state = state
    self._cancel_event = event
    self._callback = callback
    self._task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._job())

async def _job(self):
    seconds = 0
    while seconds <= self._timeout:
        if not self._cancel_event.is_set():
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            seconds += 0.1
        else:
            await self.cancel()
    await self._callback(self._query, self._state)

async def cancel(self):
    self._task.cancel()
    # Тут код, который должен выполняться при отмене таймера
    self._cancel_event.clear()
```

Модуль `confirm.py`:

```
from timer import cancel_event

@dp.callback_query_handler(state=MakeTask.confirm)
async def confirm_cb(query: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict, state: FSMContext):
    cancel_event.set()
    while cancel_event.is_set():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # Ожидание, пока эвент отмены полностью не завершится
    # Дальнейший код, который не должен выполняться, пока полностью не завершится функция в колбэке отмены
```

Всем спасибо!